# Is it possible to use QWeb template in Form view?

Tags: odoo, qweb, odoo-14

I tried to use QWeb Template in a custom view. I don't find any documentation explaining this, any reference?

Here's the sample code:

```
<record id="realestate_property_view_form" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">realestate.property.form</field>
    <field name="model">realestate.property</field>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <form string="Property">
            <header>
                <button name="approve_action" type="object" string="Approve"/>
            </header>
            <sheet>
                <group>
                    <group>
                        <field name="name" />
                        <field name="address" />
                    </group>
                    <template>
                        <t t-name="templatePreviewBox">
                            <div>
                                <img t-attf-src="'http://localhost:3000/rest/api/' + record.image_url.raw_value" />
                            </div>
                        </t>
                    </template>
                </group>
            </sheet>
        </form>
    </field>
</record>
```

The problem is that if I inspect element in the browser, it's still displayed as `<img t-attf-src>` instead of `<img src>`, and the string expression seems not evaluated.

I find the documentation in Odoo official site is not complete enough, so I really appreciate for any references or documentation about this QWeb.

Answer (score 1):

You can read in the official documentation that `form` views are composed of regular HTML with additional [structural and semantic components](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/14.0/developer/reference/addons/views.html#structural-components) and the `template` element is not one of them.

In HTML, the template element is used to declare fragments of HTML that can be cloned and inserted in the document by script. In a rendering, the template element represents nothing.

To understand how QWEB templates are rendered, refer to [QWeb Template Engine](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/14.0/developer/reference/addons/views.html#structural-components) and [QWeb Templates](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/14.0/developer/reference/javascript/qweb.html#qweb-templates).