# Can we use Qweb templates inside normal views (such as form view)

Tags: odoo, qweb

I'm trying to make some debugging in a Form view, I wrote something like this inside the notebook section of a form view:

```
<page string="test">
  <template>
        <t t-esc="Logging!"/>
        <t t-log="Logging!"/>
        <t t-raw="Logging" > </t>
  </template>
</page>
```

But nothing happens as if the  section doesn't exist.

Can't we use Qweb template inside other views?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to use QWeb template in Form view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68856264/is-it-possible-to-use-qweb-template-in-form-view)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`template` tag will not render in [form](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/15.0/developer/reference/backend/views.html#form) view. You can check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68856264/is-it-possible-to-use-qweb-template-in-form-view) for more details

You can use templates in [Activity](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/15.0/developer/reference/backend/views.html#activity), [Gantt](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/15.0/developer/reference/backend/views.html#gantt) and [Kanban](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/15.0/developer/reference/backend/views.html#kanban) views